# Unwanted scroll after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not really sure what code to post here because I don't know what could cause this and the code for this page is quite long, there is still no live version.

Basically it's a form with a few panels, only 1 is visible, when you click next the user is moved to the next screen. What happens is that when you click next there is an unwanted scroll to the footer, any idea what could cause this? view gif below:
[image]

EDIT: This is the button code:
`<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-next tuc">Next</a>`

and jQuery:

```
$('.btn-next').on('click', function(e){
        if (!$("[name='amount_tobe_charged']").val()) {
          alert('Please fill in amount');
           } else if($("[name='amount_tobe_charged']").val() < 1) {
               alert('Please enter amount');
           } else {
        var tab = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
        var nxt = $(tab).next();
        var empty = $(tab).find('.required').filter(function(){
          if($(this).attr('type') === 'email'){
            return this.value.indexOf('@') < 0;
          } else {
            return $.trim(this.value) === '';
          }
        });
        var error = $(empty[0]).attr('data-error') || 'Please fill in all fields';

        if(nxt.attr('id') === 'finish-tab'){
          submitForm(tab, nxt);
        } else {
          if(!empty.length) {
            changeTab(tab, nxt);
          } else {
            alert(error);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: can you provide the button tag

Comment: Can you show us the code behind it?

Comment: can u try with `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning btn-next tuc">Next</a>`

Comment: I saw a weird thing your console triggered a new error after clicking the button. Possibly it is causing the scroll.

Comment: @SoltaniNeji didn't work.

Comment: can u provide the submitForm function ?

Comment: It's just serializearray and submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it happening in your gif. It's because you're hiding a column that comes before the form, therefore once the column does not exist. It will push you down. You can add a scroll to get around with issue with jQuery (or vanilla but I will only provide jQuery's smooth scroll). Either implement the below and remove the `style="display: none;"` that's causing it to shift.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".form-elem").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

You'll want to place this after the column is hidden in your JS code.